# Chrome Extension : Retain modal window when page refreshes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog

In my chrome extension, I am using content script on a particular site. When a particular button is pressed, the page refreshes with new updates. Is there any way to show a Modal window or Popup, from the time the button is clicked till the page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Modal window or popup: no 
But you can use a chrome notification. It will show a customizable window which you can remember its id and take it down when the page refreshes. I do this for a popular extension i develop.

Comment: Let me try it. Also can you please tell the name of your extension, it would be a great help.

Comment: "Plus for Trello". the key part is to call the notification api from the background page.